# make a button vanish after submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css

How do I go about making this button disappear after a user submits the vote?

```
      <p id="button_<%= review.id %>"><%= f.submit "vote" %></p>
```

Comment: Yes, once the page is reloaded the button will not show.  I have a helper method that does that.

Comment: Make sure and check it in every browser if the form will continue to submit (and not be captured in an AJAX call). Otherwise, it may not work in some browsers (as in, the form may not submit) and you could get burned.

Comment: Use the form's submit event to disable the button, removing it may be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd disable the button instead of hiding; creates a less confusing interface.

You can do this most easily by just adding an `onclick` attribute:

```
<p id="button_<%= review.id %>" onclick="this.disabled=true;"><%= f.submit "vote" %></p>
```

But if you want to hide it, you can use `this.style.display='none';` instead. (If I can remember vanilla JS)

If you're already using jQuery though (or are going to be doing a lot of stuff like this):

```
$('#button_<%= review.id %>').click(function() {
    $(this).remove(); // or $(this).hide();
}
```

**edit:** [this shows the difference between Dr.Dredel's and my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/e8P4U/)

---

`onsubmit` version to make RobG happy (you have to put it on the `<form>`)

```
<form ... onsubmit="document.getElementById('button_<%= review.id %>').disabled=true;">
```

He's right that it makes more sense to do it `onsubmit`; there are other ways to submit a form such as by pressing enter. Presumably you would still want to button to get disabled in such scenarios (which if I'm not mistaken will also prevent you from submitting twice via enter)

**edit:** why yes, it does http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/9Snna/2/

Comment: I believe visiblity='hidden' is more browser universal... I've never used display to hide a button... but perhaps it's just as valid

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: You wouldn't want to set visibility=hidden in general...that might hide the element visually, but it will still take up space in the layout. Generally you want to collapse the content around it, which is what display=none does, and is actually very common and well supported. Fairly certain that's what jQuery does internally too.

Comment: +1 for disable, but please use the submit event, not the click event.

Comment: oh great! and now I can't even delete my comment!  :)  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the assumption that you want people to be able to re-visit the original page and not have the vote button show up again, not to just hide it after you click vote. If you're looking to have it disappear and use ajax, the other answers so far explain how to do that.

In your controller, look to see if someone has submitted a review for whatever it is they're reviewing.

```
#this assumes that you have foreign keys user_id and article_id in your reviews table
# and that @article and @user are the objects you're passing down
@posted_review = Review.find_by_user_id_and_article_id(@article.id, @user.id)
```

Then, in the view:

```
<% if @posted_review.nil? %>
<p id="button_<%= review.id %>"><%= f.submit "vote" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I leave @posted_review set to the actual review object so that you can access its properties if you need to, such as calling <%= @posted_review.created_at %>

Comment: +1 for explaining the ruby side of things...even though it looks like OP has that covered (comment under Q)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like he made a ninja edit after reading my post though. I thought I was getting senile there after reading your comment and seeing that above.